# View getting destroyed on orientation changes in IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swiftui

The below code represents the view of a page I am currently on. When I make a orientation change on a simulator(iPhone 12 Pro max),
I am going back to the previous page in my App. When I make the simulator go to landscape app gets back to previous page. This happens only in iPhone 12 Pro max or 11 pro max.

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation
import UIKit

struct MyRandomView: View {
    var description = ""
    var id = ""
    var name: String?
    var value: String?
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                Text(name ?? "")
                    .foregroundColor(Color(black))
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .font(.title)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                    .padding(.top, 14)
                    .padding(.bottom, 16)
                    .accessibility(addTraits: [.isHeader])
                
                Text(COVERED + (value ?? "") + ".")
                    .foregroundColor(Color(blue))
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .font(.body)
                    .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
               
                Text(message)
                    .foregroundColor(Color(.textPrimary))
                    .font(.body)
                    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                    .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                    .lineLimit(nil)
                    .padding(.top, 10)
                
                NavigationLink(
                    //TODO destination path ,
                    label: {
                        Text("UPDATE_DATA", tableName: STRING_TABLE)
                            .foregroundColor(Color(.black))
                            .font(.headline)
                            .padding(.top, 11)
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                            .padding(.bottom, 12)
                            .padding(.horizontal, 30)
                            .background(
                                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 4)
                                    .stroke(Color(blue))
                            )
                            .padding(.top, 24)
                    })
            }
            .accessibilityElement(children: .combine)
        }
        .padding(16)
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("COVERED", tableName: STRING_TABLE), displayMode: .inline)
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and review [ask]. You have not provided anywhere near enough information.

Comment: Updated the question @DonMag

Comment: try to comment out the code for NavigationLink. Does the problem still exist?

Comment: Yes the problem still exist. @workingdog